# Big Oh: T(n) = O(f(n)), G(n) = O(h(n)). Is T(G(n)) = O(h(f(n)))?

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, solution-verification, asymptotics

$T(n)= O(f(n))$ , $G(n)= O(h(n))$

How would I prove or disprove:

$  T(G(n))= O(h(f(n))$

I think this is false, because it should be $O(f(h(n)))$ instead of $O(h(f(n)))$, since G is applied before T is applied, I tried substituting polynomial functions for T and G, I think the order matters, ($n^2)!$ is not equal to ($n!)^2$ , but I am not sure if this reasoning is correct?

Comment: If the statement claims this in general, you just have to provide a counterexample.

Comment: Related to another common misconception: if $T(n) = O(f(n))$ then $e^{T(n)} = O(e^{f(n)})$.  FALSE

Answer (score 1):

This is false.
Let:
$$T(n) = 2^n = O (2^n) \\ G(n) = \lg (n!) = O(n \lg n)$$

$$T(G(n)) = 2^{\lg (n!)} \equiv n! \neq O(2^n \lg 2^n) = O(n \cdot 2^n)$$

Comment: thanks, so the statement would be true if I replace ((ℎ())) with  (ℎ(())) right?

Comment: @user624 I think it is, but this is another question whether composition of functions is monotone, i.e. if $T<G$ and $f<h$ then $T \circ G < f \circ h$ and vice versa (there is a situation that $T<G$ but $G>f$ and it can get messy I believe..) I will think about it and give you an answer if I succeed.

Comment: Consider $T(n) = f(n) = \sin (n)$, $G(n) = \frac{\pi}{2}n$ and $h(n) = \pi n$.

Comment: Great example! I wouldn't have thought about non-monotonic functions..